# How to set margins for IconGenerator in Google Map utils?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I been using google map utils for a couple of days now and it seemed so fine.

This is code im using to add a marker with a custom layout file to the map.

```
IconGenerator mIconGenerator = new IconGenerator(getApplicationContext());

View mView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_location_label, null);

TextView mInfoWindowText = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.location);

mInfoWindowText.setText(Takzy.pickupLocationText);

mIconGenerator.setContentView(mView);

mIconGenerator.setRotation(-90);

mIconGenerator.setContentRotation(90);

mIconGenerator.setContentPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

view.Bitmap mBitmapPickupLocation = mIconGenerator.makeIcon();

Bitmap mBitmapDestinationLocation = mIconGenerator.makeIcon(Takzy.destinationLocationText + " >");

// add the pickup marker to map
mMap.addMarker(
    new MarkerOptions().title(Takzy.pickupLocationText)
        .position(Takzy.pickupLatLng)
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromBitmap(mBitmapPickupLocation))
        .anchor(mIconGenerator.getAnchorU(), mIconGenerator.getAnchorV()));
```

Everything is okay but as you can see, my text gets cut from the marker label. I have tried googling, read the docs over and over, and none of them worked.

[image: issue]

it will work fine if I do not rotate the marker. but I need my marker rotated.

Can someone point out what might be the issue is?

Comment: did you get with the solution? because I'm fetching the same issue now. Thanks.

Comment: Nope. It's bug i guess